# Reasonable code-solution in my case

Tags: java

Java-studying dude here.
I've got an assignment at my school where we have made a little Star Wars game with some simple GUI. In my `SaveToFile()` method and `ReadFromFile()` methods, my method throws exceptions. 
This is alright, everything works.

But in the assignment it says: 
"Some of the methods may throw exceptions. These need to be handled reasonably."
I don´t understand what this means. It apparently has something to do with trying to avoid code-duplication. Anyone got any tips? Is it to make a method for errors that can be reused?

Here is my code:

```
private void readFromFile()
{
    try{
        gui.makeInVisible();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Savegame.obj");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        Battleground battleground = (Battleground) ois.readObject();
        GUI gui = new GUI(battleground);
        BattleController bc = new BattleController(gui, battleground);
        ois.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        gui.updateActionField("Something went wrong... Did you delete the file Savegame.obj while playing?");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException f) {
        System.out.println("Woops. This game looks broken! Did you delete the whole battleground class?");
    }
}
```

> ```
> private void saveToFile() {
>     try{
>         // Serialize data object to a file
>         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Savegame.obj"));
>         out.writeObject(battleground);
> ```

```
        Serialize data object to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
        out.close();

        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        gui.updateActionField("Something went wrong with saving the file. And we really don´t know what I am afraid!");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: `"Some of the methods may throw exceptions. These need to be handled reasonably."` Simply put, if a piece of code in your program is prone to throw an exception, you should handle it using try/catch blocks.

Comment: Without code showing the method signature that throws the excrotion(s), and some code around where it is called, we can't realistically answer your question

Comment: OK, so it might be what I have already done then. I thought it had something to do with a method to be released if for instance IOException was met.

But allright, thanks.

Comment: Now I updated the code. But I think I got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you already did some "reasonable handling of the exceptions" for a school assignment, but you should still add a finally block where you close the outputstreams. If an excepion occurs now, the stream will never be closed.

Comment: Java's not quite *that* fragile.  :)  A `FileInputStream` has a finalizer that ensures it is closed before the object dies.  (A JVM that does escape analysis could clean it up immediately.)  It's still definitely better to explicitly close the stream yourself, but forgetting to do so will typically just tie up the file for a while til GC gets around to closing it.

Answer (score 2):

`SaveToFile` and `ReadFromFile` may throw `Exception`s if for example the file is not found, what the assignment is asking is that you do not let these exceptions propagate and break your program in the case they will happen.

What this means in a technical point of view is that you should be doing something like this (suppose this is your `ReadFromFile`, I wrote it without testing is just to explain the point):

```
try {
    String sCurrentLine;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // here you should handle the IOException, maybe you want
    // to notify the user, or probably exit the program with 
    // a log in the console or whatever else
}
```

Generally speaking is not a good idea to let `Exception`s propagate, you should handle them as soon as you're in a point in your code that could deal with them; without knowing your code my assumption is that you should do that right away in the method that reads from the file and notify the user right away.

As @cHao suggested in the comments it would not be a proper solution to give `ReadFromFile` the responsability of notifying the user, depending on how you structured your code you might want to let the `Exception` propagate further up, until you reach a class that, with a wider understanding of the application, can choose what to do.

Comment: Handle them *where you can*, though.  And logging, showing an error message, etc...are not actually handling.  If all you can do is say "OMG OMG ERROR!!!", then you typically *shouldn't* be catching the exception.  Just let it propagate in that case; the caller should be ready to catch it and suggest using another file or whatever.

Comment: Uhm yeah I agree, I said "you should handle them as soon as you're in a point in your code that could deal with them"; I think that notifying the user is way better than nothing, we could agree or not that this could be called "handling the exception", but still it's an improvement

Comment: It could remotely be considered an improvement iff the exception is rethrown.  Otherwise, though, you've just robbed the caller, and its caller, etc, of the chance to actually *handle* the exception -- ie: to *fix the cause* of it.  And the caller's probably in a better position to do so, as it sees a bigger part of the overall picture.

Comment: That depends on how the caller of this code is organized, but let's say that such a caller exists, what would you do there?

Comment: For one, if `Savegame.obj` isn't found, the caller could be like "Saved game not found.  *Would you like to start a new game?*"  That's an option that `readFromFile` shouldn't even be considering, because its one and only job is to *read from the file*.  But the caller has a bigger view of things, and can reasonably propose that option.

Comment: Got your point, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: I updated the answer with your useful insights, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use exceptions in your code you must handle them also in those places where you use your functions. Each time you treat or handle an exception you could log the exception, print it out etc... but the handling itself is very specific to every situations.

There is no 'magic code for all exceptions'. It's your job to recover and act accordingly in each situation.

There a plenty of tutorials about right exception handling in the net, like this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

And do not call a function that could launch an exception without handling them because this will lead to crashes of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into Exception Handling in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

You will probably understand what are the kind of exceptions, which you should handle and which not, and different ways to handle the exceptions/errors.

Probably in your cases you have to catch the exceptions and throw custom exception, or may just show a more resonable comment/log.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch any exceptions thrown from File Input/Output, and do any cleaning up code, like closing connections. Its also good to display an error message to the user.

That's what I would call "reasonably"